# Hadoop how to allocate more memory per node

Tags: hadoop, memory, config

I have a Hadoop cluster running on 2 nodes(master and slave) each of which have 
126GB RAM and 32 CPU.
when I run my cluster i am only able to see 8 GB memory per node. How do I increase this? What would be the optimal memory to be allocated per node and how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This blog post will give you a ton of help; http://hortonworks.com/blog/how-to-plan-and-configure-yarn-in-hdp-2-0/

Comment: I went the above post but that did not help in my case. One thing I do notice is for my setup of disk I have single large disk instead of multiple small disks as in the example. Any idea if that makes any difference?

Comment: With `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` set to 96GB and `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` to 8GB per container, you should be able to get about 12 containers.  The 1-master/1-worker setup should only be good for simple POC.  As for the disk concerns, YARN doesn't know exactly how many disks you have, but to truly allow Hadoop to run well you have to account for the underlying conventions/assumptions of a JBOD setup with some appropriate ratio between drives, CPU cores and memory such as my 1-2-10 recommendation called out at [link](https://martin.atlassian.net/wiki/x/DgDvAQ).

Comment: I went through the post above post. It did help me in increasing memory limits. but my job gets stuck after around 50% of map is complete & reduce yet to start. What would help me.

Comment: Archived link: https://web.archive.org/web/20170610145449/http://hortonworks.com/blog/how-to-plan-and-configure-yarn-in-hdp-2-0/

Answer (score 1):

You might have to tell Hadoop what parameters to use when launching the JVMs or else it will use your Java implementation default values.

In your `mapred-site.xml`, you can add this `mapred.child.java.opts` field to specify the memory size to use for the JVMs.

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx16000m</value>
</property>
```

Where 16000 is the number of MB you want to allocate to each JVM.

I hope it helps!

[Source](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W265aa64a4f21_43ee_b236_c42a1c875961/page/Tuning%20the%20heap%20size%20of%20map%20and%20reduce%20tasks)

Comment: I am doing this using conf.set("mapred.child.java.opts",opts); where I pass the required memory size per child as a parameter. My problem is I want to use more RAM available on my machine for each node but the node gets a max of 8 GB.